# How to verify numeric dates for incorrect values?

Tags: r

This is my sample dataset, imported from an excel file with all the columns parsed as characters.

```
     id     date
1    1139   21567 
2    2937   27144
3    1933   02/04 /1977
```

When later converting the date column with `as.Date(as.numeric(df$date),origin = "1899-12-30")`, as some dates come in a dirty format, there will be NA's.

Can you please advise on a validation script that would check for incorrect values (patterns different than #####) and throw as an output the `id` so it can be manually verified?

```
id 1933 has an incorrect date
```

Comment: What is expected output for your sample data?

Comment: `subset(DF, nchar(date) != 5) `will list all rows whose date is not 5 characters.

Comment: Why not check which of those dates turn into NA, and report id based on that? Use the `is.na` function for that. Might check that it is also less than some value, as what ever date comes from 99999 is unlikely to be a real date.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below:

```
# create a dataframe

id<-c(1139,2937,1933)
date<-c(2156,27144,"02/04 /1977")
df <- data.frame(id, date)

#create a column to find non-numeric characters in date column

df$IsNum <- !(is.na(as.numeric(df$date)))

#filter dataframe
df[ which(df$IsNum=='FALSE'),]
```

This will return:
[image: output]